# The dots from my nav-bar are not being removed

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

I have read through my small code and want the dots removed from my nav-bar. I have already explored other similar questions on stack over flow and tried their answer. But the outcome that I have seen is that is still not removing the dots but when I type in the code in code.io it removes it for me: https://codepen.io/abhirajsb/pen/xxVLrpW.

My  HTML code in my code editor(VS-CODE):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
   <title>Multi-Vitamins</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <header id="header">
     <img src="image/LOGO.jpg" alt="Multi-Vitamins" id="header-img" />
     <nav id="nav-bar">
         <ul>
           <li><a href="#About" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
           <li><a href="#Work" class="nav-link">How it works</a></li>
           <li><a href="#Pricing" class="nav-link">Pricing</a></li>
         </ul>
     </nav>
   </header>
 </body>
</html>
```

My CSS code:

```
li {
 list-style-type: none;
 padding: 0%;
 margin: 0%;
}
```

The output on my extension live is always showing the dots:
[image]

Comment: Where is the <link /> in the header to the CSS?

Comment: The codepen doesn't seem to have the dots

Comment: You just try list-style: none instead of list-style-type: none;

Comment: Maybe you should remove the CSS and HTML tag since the issue is obviously from visual studio , Also make it clear which version you use . . You'll get a chance to have an efficient answer

Answer (score 1):

Try This in the header replace styles.css with ur css:

```
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
```

Comment: thank you Davor. It has helped me. Was such a silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please show us your CSS code? if this is all you have. Could you please try to do a hard reset. by clicking `Ctrl + shift + R`  in your browser and check again with our answers.

Or try to run it on your local device. I don't see ay problem with your code as it run without any problem. anyway I tried it with `list-style: none;` and it worked

```
 ul {
        list-style: none;
    }
```

that would solve your problem. if that doesn't work please let me know.

```css
  ul {
        list-style: none;
    }
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <img src="image/LOGO.jpg" alt="Multi-Vitamins" id="header-img" />
  <nav id="nav-bar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#About" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Work" class="nav-link">How it works</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Pricing" class="nav-link">Pricing</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: read the question again, he knows it works, even in the codepen , but not with the tool he uses . Question should be clarified ;)

Comment: Well, then it makes no sense.

Comment: because he uses a prog to build its app and he probably don't even run it in a regular browser to view it ... or the view is not being updated ...

Comment: oh. that might be the case then.

Answer (score 0):

You just try **list-style: none** instead of list-style-type: none;
[image]

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0%;
  margin: 0%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Multi-Vitamins</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header id="header">
      <img src="image/LOGO.jpg" alt="Multi-Vitamins" id="header-img" />
      <nav id="nav-bar">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#About" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Work" class="nav-link">How it works</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Pricing" class="nav-link">Pricing</a></li>
          </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: list-style:none; is valid : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style

Answer (score 0):

I simply forgot to reference CSS style sheet to my HTML sheet.

solved it.